# AWS OCSP Stapling

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, aws-lambda, ocsp

After creating an OCSP server via Python3.6 + Lambda + Serverless + DynamoDB + S3 and OpenSSL it has become necessary to support `OpenSSL --version` of `1.1` which supports the multiple `-cert` options, thus reducing overhead and network requests.

With `print('Openssl version in lambda:', ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)` I can see that the installed version is: `OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010`. How feasible it is to upgrade the version on `AWS Lambda`?

Also can `OCSP Stapling` disussed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-ocsp-stapling be used in the set up above to reduce network requests and load?

Comment: Think link may help you. This link shows how to include openssl in the Lambda package: https://github.com/kiddouk/letslambda

Comment: @andrea-f what isn't clear from your question is why you needed an OSCP server, and that seems relevant.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks for the link. I know how to include OpenSSL, I need to know how to update it to the latest version though which is not bundled in Lambda

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot for broadcast signaling device auth